# Firebase Cloud Messaging not showing Server Key

Tags: android, ios, firebase, google-cloud-platform, push-notification

Does anyone know where I can find the Server Key shown in this picture? The problem is that Firebase slightly changed the UI and now I don't know where to find it.

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/ru5Ou.png]

Comment: I need this as well, I was using Amazon SNS and adding the server key into it. Did you ever find out where it is?

Answer (score 23):

Firebase cloud messaging is now shifted to API (V1)

So to get the `serverkey` you should enable the cloud messaging API (Legacy).

Follow the steps:

1. Click on the three dots and click on manage Api in google cloud console
   [image]
2. Click on enable.
   [image]

3.Now redirect back to the main page and refresh the page.

Now you have your `serverkey`

Hope it helps!

Answer (score 3):

From Firebase Cloud Messaging API (V1), we have to enable the cloud messaging service.

1. Open project settings and select cloud messaging tab
2. Select three dot menu right to Cloud Messaging API (Legacy) and tap Manage API in Google Cloud Console
3. In the redirected Google Cloud Console enable the cloud messaging service.
4. Go back to project settings and refresh. You can get the server key now.

Reference - https://documentation.onesignal.com/docs/generate-a-google-server-api-key

Answer (score 1):

I was able to get the Server key by doing the following steps:

1. Click on the "..." next to "Cloud Messaging API (Legacy)"
2. Go back to the previous page and refresh and you should now see the Server Key

Not sure if we need to do something different moving forward now that it's considered legacy....

Answer (score 0):

you might not find the Fcm automatically enabled as Google suggests the FCM API V1 for sending cloud messaging.
Now you might have to manually enable the Fcm application so as to get access to the SERVER KEY

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).